# How to fill a LWUIT Button with an image when it's focused?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a button in LWUIT Form, and I have an icon that should be drawn in this button, I want the icon to fill all the button space without leaving any white space between the button border and the icon in it, how could I do this ?

**For example:** let's assume the icon is simply a green square, using the following code:

```
Button button = new Button(Image.createImage("/green.JPG"));
form.addComponent(button);
```

I got the following result **when the item is focused**:

[image]

How can I remove the **white border** surrounding the "green" icon of the button **when it's focused** (I'll replace the whole icon image with another image to represent the focus state) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The gap, which is the white border, between the content, the green icon, and the component boundary is called the *padding*. To fit the image with button boundaries, remove the padding in all direction (*TOP*, *BOTTOM*, *LEFT* and *RIGHT*) in each of the component states, viz *Unselected*, *Selected*, *Pressed* and *Disabled*.

So for unselected state it is

```
button.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

do this for other state's of the button.

You might want to play around with the margin of the button to fit it suitably within the container.

---

2) To remove the border of the button call the below syntactic method for each component state

```
button.get[ComponentState]Style().setBorder(null, false);
```

In your case for focused state, `button.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(null, false);`

---

3) To set the icon for the appropriate state of button use the following methods,

```
button.setIcon(image);                  
button.setRollOverIcon(image);
button.setPressedIcon(image);
```

Comment: Correct. For completeness though I would add that all of this can be defined in the GUI theme editing without actually writing any code. Just set the padding to 0 and the border to empty within the theme style for button (or even the default style).